# Incluir dos DataType en un constructor clase c++

Tags: c++, c++11

**Este es el diagrama de mis DataTypes.**
[image: Este es el diagrama de mis DataTypes.]

```
DtViaje::DtViaje(float precioTotal, DtFecha fecha, DtVehiculo vehiculo, int duracion, int distancia):DtViajeBase(fecha, duracion, distancia){
this->fecha=fecha;
this->duracion=duracion;
this->distancia=distancia;
this->precioTotal=precioTotal;
this->vehiculo=vehiculo;
```

}

Ese es el Constructor de un DataType del cual necesito hacer uso. Es una herencia de un DtViajeBase, por lo cual como se ve le agrego los parametros que hereda para que funcione correctamente. Pero tambien necesito pasarle parametros para que ese **DtVehiculo** me lo tome, de otra manera me tira error que espera 3 parametros (el DtVehiculo son 3 parametros) y le envio 0(cero).

Aqui el error que me genera el compilador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar la declaración de la clase DtVehiculo y el lugar donde instancias y pasas al constructor de DtViaje?

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que la manera en la que se está instanciando el objeto DtViaje no es correcta.

Se le deben pasar instancias de objetos a las instancias de DtViaje (como la de DtVehiculo). Un ejemplo sería:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DtViajeBase
{
    public:
        DtViajeBase(int a);
};

class DtVehiculo
{
    public:
        DtVehiculo(int a, int b, int c);
};

class DtViaje : public DtViajeBase
{
    public:
        DtViaje(int a, DtVehiculo vehiculo);
};
DtViaje::DtViaje(int a, DtVehiculo vehiculo):DtViajeBase(a) {

}

int main() {
    DtVehiculo vehiculo(1, 2, 3);

    DtViaje viaje(1, vehiculo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yo no necesito instanciar la clase, de hecho, hacer la instancia DtViaje viaje(1, DtVehiculo(1,2,3)) no me genera problemas, de hecho puedo hacerlo perfectamente en otros lados.

Mi problema es en ese constructor puntual, son DataTypes todo lo que estoy manejando ahi mismo.

Comment: Entonces, no entiendo cuál es el problema. Lo siento.

Comment: ```DtViaje::DtViaje(float precioTotal, DtFecha fecha, DtVehiculo vehiculo, int duracion, int distancia):DtViajeBase(fecha, duracion, distancia){```

En ese constructor, tengo una herencia y un DtVehiculo. A la derecha de los **:** tengo que poner los aatributos heredados, pero tambien el compilador espera que yo le ponga la informacion de DtVehiculo para que compile y es ahi donde no se como agregarlo.

Gracias igualmente! Se valora el tiempo de responder

Comment: Ese constructor me parece correcto, no entiendo cuál es el problema en esa línea. ¿Podrías pegar la línea donde realizas la instancia de DtViaje?

Comment: Es que no logro instanciar nada cuando ni tan siquiera me compila por no poder hacer un constructor bien. Ese es el punto.

El problema reside alli, si no, yo no te entiendo a ti a que te refieres con instanciar el constructor.

Comment: He actualizado el código con un ejemplo que compila (realizando algo mucho más sencillo). Lo tienes declarado así?

Comment: Si, esta de esa manera, pero teniendolo asi es cuando me genera el error que te comento. Me pide que le indique mas informacion sobre el DtVehiculo.
Quizas este error solo lo genera Codeblocks y no por consola, gracias! Viendo que te compila a ti y a mi no, debe venir por ahi el error.

Comment: Qué raro. ¿Puedes añadir la clase DtVehiculo, junto con toda su herencia? Yo diría que el problema está en ella.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error se puede reproducir con este sencillo código:

```
struct A
{
    A(int, int, int){}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
}

B b;
```

Como puedes ver, el objeto `A` tiene un constructor que requiere tres parámetros, y dicho objeto está contenido en el objeto `B`, como no le dices a `B` como construir el `A` que contiene, [el compilador se queja](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/v7ikqDS5RMGRq5qL01EjM69ERwFGaFbXctVac3FBlTiBlSgkWnPVcnEBpRVyEzPzNDRBok4KSdZcnEWpJaVFeQoGQAX//wMA):

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
> note: candidate: ‘A::A(int, int, int)’
>          A(int, int, int){}
>          ^
> note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
> ```

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Proporciona un constructor por defecto para el primer objeto:

   ```
   struct A
   {
       A() {}
       A(int, int, int) {}
   }

   struct B
   {
       A a;
   }
   ```

   De esta manera, el objeto `B` sabrá cómo construir su objeto `A` contenido: basta con construir por defecto.
2. Explica al objeto `B` como construir un objeto `A` añadiendo en el constructor del primero la construcción del segundo:

   ```
   struct A
   {
       A(int, int, int) {}
   }

   struct B
   {
       B() : a(1, 2, 3) {} // Construye el objeto A contenido en B.
       A a;
   }
   ```

Comment: No es el error, repito nuevamente. Cuando hago la herencia esta totalmente correcto. Siempre que evite poner otro DtType mas en el constructor.
```DtViaje::DtViaje(DtVehiculo vehiculo,float precioTotal, DtFecha& fecha, int duracion, int distancia):DtViajeBase(fecha, duracion, distancia),DtVehiculo(nroSerie, porcentajeBateria, precioBase){
    this->fecha=fecha;
    this->duracion=duracion;
    this->distancia=distancia;
 this->precioTotal=precioTotal;
 this->vehiculo=vehiculo;
}
```

Alli, si yo le quito el DtVehiculo Vehiculo me funciona perfecto, pero necesito que este

Comment: Disculpas pefro no entiendo como poner codigo, le puse las ``` y sale mal.

Pero como digo, si le quito el DtVehiculo vehiculo, me compila perfecto la herencia.
Pero dejandolo me pide que le ponga los parametros del DtVehiculo en el constructor y eso es lo que no se resolver. Gracias

Comment: Si no es el error, y has tenido que repetir una explicación, seguramente tu pregunta esté mal redactada.